# Lenovo drivers do not send auto adjust information to a monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, external-display

Lenovo drivers do not seem to provide any external monitor with how it should auto adjust. Is this correct behavior?

I've noticed with a few Lenovo branded monitors (thinkvision L1711pC and below), new generation Lenovo laptops (specifically the T440s and T540 series) don't communicate with the monitor correctly when using a VGA adapter.

The auto adjust feature on the monitor runs but leaves a half inch black bar on one side. I have tried forcing new monitor drivers as well as new video drivers directly from Intel. The video chipset is the Intel HD 4400 series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No driver sends auto adjust information to the monitor. It is exactly the other way round.

Immediately after plugging in the monitor, it starts sending the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) to the video card via [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) protocol. The EDID contains information about the monitor's supported resolutions and most importantly, the optimal resolution and refresh rate.

If this transfer happens, the video card should calibrate the signal according to the monitor. If in this situation, the monitor is not auto adjusting correctly, then it is a monitor problem!

If you want to see if the EDID was really transferred or understood by the video card, look at **Device Manager** at the monitor or at the resolution changing dialog at the monitor. If you see a manufacturer name and / or **Plug-and-Play Monitor** everything is OK. Otherwise, if it shows **Non Plug-and-Play monitor**, the video card doesn't know anything about the monitor (because the monitor doesn't send that information) and it tries a common resolution and refresh rate. In this situations you can expect wrong auto adjustment.